# ¿Android con python?

Tags: android, python-3.x

Necesito saber si hay alguna **forma** de hacer un ***proyecto/libreria/o algo q pueda usar*** en una aplicacion android...

Me refiero a que en un activity de mi **aplicacion** por ejemplo le pase un **array bidimensional** y con un apartado **python** que se supone q funcione dentro de **android**

### (la pregunta en si)

convertirla en una **matriz** y trabajar con ella y devolver un resultado en forma de **array bidimensional**... Haber para aclarar un poco una **dll** se puede crear en cualquier lenguaje y es universal para cualqier lenguaje mientras el destino sea una aplicacion de **consola** o una **GUI**(pueden existir otras de ser asi no las conozco)...

Eso es exactamente lo que qiero saber si se puede o no hacer con ***android*** y ***python***.

Comment: ¿Podrías poner un título más «interesante» y acorde que describa un poco el problema?

Comment: espero haber satisfacido tu critica ;)

Comment: haber «satisfecho» ...

Comment: jajaja @Shaz pos si... usted sabe mas que yo debo respetarlo gracias x la critica

Comment: Quieres correr un script Python en un sistema android?

Comment: No entedí aún qué necesitas, pero quizás [Chaquopy](https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/) o [Kivy](https://kivy.org/#home) te sirvan.

Comment: Quieres usar una matriz hecha en Python y manejarla en Java? O quieres pasar una matriz de Java, procesarla en Python y luego regrese a Java? Leí varias veces y no entendí que necesitas :/

Comment: @ChristopherVivarVivar es lo segundo que mencionas lo que exactamente qiero lograr... es pasar un arreglo bidimensional a un no se como se llame exactamente si script/biblioteca no se hecho en python y que me devulva un array bidimensional

Comment: Tal como dice @abulafia puedes usar chaquopy, aquí sale explicado cómo llamar un script o clase. https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/doc/current/android.html. Instancias y luego retornas en la variable, si nos orientas que vas a hacer específicamente quizá podamos ayudarte a aplicar directamente en Java y ahorrarte tanto problema. A menos que quieras usar librerías grandes como pandas o similares.

Comment: gracias déjame intentar con chaquopy haber...